Prove the set $U=\{x\in C[0,1]| x(1)\neq x(0)\}$ is not connected

For two functions $x$ and $y$ in $C[0,1]$, define
$$d(x,y)=\max\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}|x(t)-y(t)|.$$Admit that
$(C[0,1],d)$ is complete. Set $U=\{x\in C[0,1]| x(1)\neq x(0)\}$
and define $$\varphi: C[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}: x\mapsto x(1)-x(0).$$
(a) Prove that $\varphi$ is continuous.
(b) Deduce that $U$ is not connected.

My attempt:
a) Consider $x\in C[0,1]$ and $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $C[0,1]$ that converges to $x$.
Then $x_n$ converges pointwisely to $x$. In particular, we have $x_n(1)\longrightarrow x(1)$, $x_n(0)\longrightarrow x(0)$ as $n\to\infty\Rightarrow x_n(1)-x_n(0)\longrightarrow x(1)-x(0)$ as $n\to\infty$ or $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\varphi (x_n)=\varphi (x)$, which means $\varphi$ is continuous.
b) Assume $U$ is connected. Since $\varphi$ is continuous, $\varphi (U)$ must be connected. I'm stuck here. I don't know how can I go further. I would be very appreciated if someone can continue this path or have other ways to deal with part b). Thanks in advance.

$\{x: \phi (x)<0 \}$ and $\{x: \phi (x)>0\}$ are disjoint non-empty open sets whose union is $U$.

Nice! Silly me :)

If $U$ was connected, then $\varphi(U)$ would be connected too. As the only connected sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are intervals, $\varphi(U)$ would be an interval.
Now, as $x(1)\neq x(0)$ for all $x\in U$ we have $0\notin \varphi(U)$.
Nonetheless, defining $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$ we have $f,g\in U$ and $\varphi(f)=1$, $\varphi(g)=-1$.
Thus, $1\in \varphi(U)$ and $-1\in\varphi(U)$. As $0\notin \varphi(U)$ this means $\varphi(U)$ is not an interval, a contradiction.

Nice solution! :)
